# Creating Asana tasks by email

Tags: email, header, task, asana, trello

I wanna create tasks in [Asana](http://asana.com) by email. I've found [this link](http://help.asana.com/customer/portal/articles/69313), which describes how to do this, but creating is restricted to 'from' email header.

So, my question is: **"Is it possible to create asana tasks by email, not from the 'from' email header, but from other email headers?"**

*if you know, how to do this in [Trello](https://trello.com/), you're welcome.*

Comment: I also would like to know if this (generally creating a card from email) is possible in Trello.

Comment: Creating cards by email is now a feature of Trello. Here's a link to the Trello documentation on this feature: http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1216141-creating-cards-by-email

Answer (score 1):

*Answer on the "bonus" question*:
There is a card in trello development board about this. So this is being discussed...
See https://trello.com/c/245izli3

Comment: Creating cards by email is now a feature of Trello. You should update your answer. Here's a link to the Trello documentation on this feature: http://help.trello.com/customer/portal/articles/1216141-creating-cards-by-email